# How to open a certain question in the Close Votes queue?

Tags: support, review, vote-to-close

Unlike the `edit`-button which brings me to the `Suggested Edits`-queue when an edit is pending, the `close`-button always open the VTC-dialog.

I'd prefer to be brought to the `Close Votes`-queue if there are close votes already, because only here I can vote to leave the question open.

So how can I open a certain question in the `Close Votes`-queue?

Comment: "edit" button does not bring me to the "Suggested Edits" queue, it just opens a pop-up to only accept/reject the edit made to the current post. Am I missing something? Do you  mean 'opening the "edit" link in a new tab'?

Comment: @pomsky Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd prefer that too :/

Unfortunately, only mods can do that.

See [this feature request on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/318248/review-close-votes-on-question-you-are-currently-viewing).

When I want to find the review of a post, I look at the [review history page](https://askubuntu.com/review/close/history) and scroll through the recent pages to find the post I want (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> is helpful), but this page only shows the history of reviews by everyone to users who have >10k reputation - otherwise it shows you your *own* reviews only, which is not helpful for this purpose. This also doesn't work if nobody has reviewed the post yet (for example, it received close votes from users who landed on the page; some questions get closed before anyone reviews them in the queue, but in such cases the closure is usually correct).

Only completed reviews are accessible in the post's timeline, so that also does not help.

In short, there is no easy way to vote to Leave Open from a question page. If you post the question link in [the Downboat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3877/raiders-of-the-lost-downboat) I or someone else will be willing to look for it in the history or let you know if we encounter it in the queue and give you a link.

Answer (score 5):

To add to Zanna's answer, since we are <10k rep users, what I usually do is filter the Close Votes queue to certain criteria of a question I want to vote on.

If I take this question as an example: [console command or Putty not working "Access denied" in Ubuntu 17](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132067/console-command-or-putty-not-working-access-denied-in-ubuntu-17)

Clicking the close button, I can see that the question is being closed as *unclear* and *off-topic*. Also, it has the following tags: [14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/14.04)[command-line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/command-line)[putty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/putty)

However, the [14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/14.04) is quite broad so I usually ignore it.
[image: VTC menu]

Next, I go to the [Close Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/close) queue and click on the `filter` link at the top near the title. Finally, I filter based on the previous criteria so I get that question in order to review it.

[image: Filtering the Close Votes Review Queue]

P.S. This isn't a 100% optimal solution, sometimes I may need to review a couple of questions first before reaching the one I was searching for. And sometimes the tags all too broad for this to work at all. But more often than not, this method works.